# Use tampermonkey to read json answers of a website in realtime (parsing json)

Tags: json, real-time, tampermonkey

I'm trying to automate a part of my daily work on a website I'm using (not developping). I have to crawl several lists on the website, dig an item in the list, to check some values, and do it again and again ...

Im used to developping in Powershell and python, not with a web browser. I have limited rights on the machine I'm working on. The only solution I can easily deploy is a tampermonkey/greasemonkey on a firefox portable. I'd like to use this to catch the json answers of the website (all of them), parse the answers for some values, and automate some kind of popup "Hey, This item in the list is between 90 and 100 !"

No code to show yet, that's what i'm looking for : basic solution for json interception while i'm crawling.

I have good knowledge of json parsing using python, the hard part for me is catching the answers ...

Thank you very much for any help you can give. And apologies for my average english ...

Comment: It depends on how those jsons are being loaded. If it's via XHR/fetch look for examples of intercepting these in a userscript (like [this one](/a/629753)).

Comment: I can see the content of the json in the Konsole / Network / XHR list, by cliking on one item in the list ... will read your link ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that tampermonkey can intercept jsons on page load, not afterwards. Closing question.

Comment: Would be nice with a link to the answer.